# Hooking up D3 with MeanJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, meanjs

I am trying to get d3 and angular working together using the [MeanJS](http://meanjs.org/) framework. I have used D3 alot but very new to meanJS and angular. The best practice seems to be to put the d3 code in a directive. I already had a CRUD module created called customers, so I used the following command:

```
yo meanjs:angular-directive mus-example
```

This has generated the directive file, hooked it all up and given me the following code (except for my comment I have added):

```
'use strict';



angular.module('customers').directive('musExample', [
function() {
return {
template: '<div></div>',
restrict: 'E',
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                //I want to add my d3 code here

                element.text('this the musExample directive');
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I have tested it out using  and all is good. The directive prints out the element.text so no problem

So now I want to put my D3 code in. I have installed d3 by running
    bower install d3

This appears to have updated the env/all.js file and I can see d3 loading in the browser. But as soon as I try and use D3 code in the directive I get the kind of error like below.

```
  public/modules/customers/directives/mus-example.client.directive.js
 13 |                 var color = d3.scale.category10();
                                  ^ 'd3' is not defined.
```

What I am really after is some hello-world example of how to hook d3 into meanJS via a directive. I think there is some kind of config file or something I am not  updating with the d3 and pretty sure this is something really simple, I just am still not comfortable with meanjs. Hooking up d3 and Angular is really easy, there is just something going on here that has to do with me not understanding meanjs properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add - I did update the bower.json file and the all.js files in the MeanJS App. I have also read that the applicationModuleVendorDependencies should be updated, but when I include d3 there, it breaks everything

Comment: The other really weird thing going on here is that is I put in console.log(d3) where I am going to add my d3 code above, I can see it in the console - so its somehow loaded and available. But I still get the error message above.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add `d3.js` to files in `config/env`

Example:

https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/config/env/production.js

Comment: Thanks, this got me at first, but even when updating env/production and env/all, still didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible answer for this thanks to some code found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-charting-directives-using-angularjs-d3-js/) . It looks like an issue working with d3 and the generated directive code from yo in MeanJS, so I have tweaked the directive code and also used the angular $window object to get hold of the d3. I can kind of see how this works but would be interested to see if people thought this was best practice or there was a better way - this does the job but it does not seem quite right.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('customers').directive('musExample',   
    function($window) {
        return {
            template: '<div></div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                var d3 = $window.d3;
            // example of d3 at work

                var canvas = d3.select('mus-example')
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', 100)
                    .attr('height', 200);


               var circle = canvas.append('circle')
                    .attr('cx', 30)
                    .attr('cy', 30)
                    .attr('r', 24)
                    .attr('fill', 'blue');

            }
        };
    }
);
```